# The best way to display video from camera in Qt WebKit bridge

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I'm developing an application that loads frames from an ethernet camera and displays these frames in an  element within a Qt QWebView.
So I would like to ask, which is the best or the most efficient way to display images in sequence from the camera, so that it would display as a live video for the user.